# MongoDB evaluate field name dynamically

Tags: mongodb

I have an example document

```
{
  field1: 'a',
  field2: 'b',
  field3: 'c',
  field4: 'd',
  field5: 'field1'
}
```

how can I use field5 in a mongodb query
I am looking to get the value of field in field5 ( something like document[ field5[field1] ] )

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         result: {
            $filter: {
               input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
               cond: { $eq: ["$$this.k", "field5"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $project: { result: { $first: "$result.v" } } }
])
```